# Highmaps: PHP $_GET[] with JQuery Ajax: sending a value to the same page and capturing with PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, highcharts, highmaps

I've built a map with PHP and Highmaps (from Highcharts libraries) which loads data from a SQL Server database. So far so good! But now I want to send a value from the map to another PHP page using Ajax since I want to send the name of the point clicked by the user.

```js
series: {
    cursor: 'pointer',
    point: {
        events:{
            click:function(){
                var myVariable = this.name;
              $.get('my_page.php',{"brazil_state":myVariable});
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After doing this on the same page:

```html
<?php

  $brazil_state = $_GET['brazil_state'];

  $stmt = "select * from [DATABASE].[dbo].[MY_TABLE] where   state = '{$brazil_state}'";

  $stmt_exec = sqlsrv_query($conn, $stmt);

  while($rows = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt_exec)){
    print_r($rows);
  }

?>
```

And this would bring to me all the results that satisfy the condition of the query, but the parameter is not being parsed from JQuery Ajax to the PHP $_GET.

I've searched the answer, but I haven't found any yet.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Have you at least tried basic debugging like... `var_dump($_GET);`?

Comment: Yes, but the page returns an empty array (array(0) { }).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a way to solve my question:

```js
series: {
  cursor: 'pointer',
  point: {
    events:{
      click:function(){
        //open div with JQuery UI fold function
        $( "#folder" ).show( "fold", 1000 );
        //sends the request to details.php and brings the result into the div id='folder' on the current page
        $.ajax({
          url: 'details.php?state=' + this.name,
          success: function(data) {
            $('#folder').html(data);
          }
        });
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Thank you, people!

Answer (score 0):

In the second codesnippet you reference the variable $_GET['myVariable'], but the name of the variable you use in the ajax-request:

`$.get('my_page.php',{"brazil_state":myVariable});`

is "brazil_state"

Comment: I am sorry! It was a mistake. When I was translating to English I missed this part. I edited the snippet. Thank you very much!